# Prolog sum all the number in the list.

Tags: list, prolog

How to sum all odd positioned elements in a list

example [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] = 25

```
odd([],0].
odd([Z],Z).
odd([X,Y|T], Sum+1):- odd(T,Sum).
```

but it return me 1+3+5+7+9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you construct when you write `Sum+1` is a term with functor `'+'/2` and arguments `Sum` and `1`.

In Prolog, when you want to calculate a sum, you need to use the predicate `is/2`.

In your code, you should also add cuts to remove unnecessary choicepoints, and add `X` to the rest of the sum, not `1`:

```
odd([],0) :- !.
odd([Z],Z) :- !.
odd([X,_|T],Sum):- odd(T,Sum0), Sum is Sum0+X.
```

Using an accumulator would allow you to make the code tail-recursive...

Comment: I got false return with your method. Thanks

Comment: I forgot the `Sum` parameter in the third clause. Thanks for notifying me. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In prolog you have to use the `is` operator when you want to evaluate arithmetic expressions. Since you use the `+` symbol outside of an arithmetic scope it is not interpreted specially. This appears to be homework, so I'll give a simplified example:

```
add(A, B, C) :- C is A + B.
```

The code above adds `A` and `B` and stores the result in `C`.

Comment: odd([],0].
odd([Z],Z).
odd([X,Y|T], Sum):- Sum1 is Sum + X, odd(T,Sum1 ). Is this correct but I got error will run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list with the odd elements, then sum that list:

```
divide([], [], []).
divide([H|T], [H|L1], L2) :- divide(T, L2, L1).

sum(L, Sum) :- sum(L, 0, Sum).

sum([], Acu, Acu).
sum([H|T], Acu, Acu1) :-
  Acu2 is Acu + H,
  sum(T, Acu2, Acu1).

sum_odd(L, Sum) :-
  divide(L, Odds, _),
  sum(Odds, Sum).

:- sum_odd([1,2,5,6,8,9,1], Sum), writeln(Sum).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([],0).
sum([H|T],N) :-
       sum(T,M), N is H + M.
```